# calculate summary statistics of numeric columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table contains 25 numeric columns and i am trying to get the summary statistics(mean ,median,min,max,missing count) of numeric columns .

I am able to do this by each column and it is lot of manual work

```
eg: select min(col1),max(col1),mean(col1),stdev(col1) from table;
```

Is there any better approach to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can express this as one query, using a lateral join:

```
select colname, min(val), max(val), avg(val), stddev(val)
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), . . .
     ) v(colname, val)
group by colname;
```